# Referencing C++ component in XAML app

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, opencv, windows-phone

I have downloaded openCV "OpenCVXaml" sample and built them according to readme file. After upgrading project to windows phone silverlight 8.1 I was able to build it.

[image: solution explorer]

After launching it an Exception is thrown at first reference to OpenCV dlls.

[image: exception]

I did not touch dlls item types. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the missing dll to the project  and mark it as content. This might resolve your problem.

Comment: It works. However I have no idea why samples didnt have that thing configured... Thanks!